# Swift error - ADAL library

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, authentication, adal

Does anyone know why am I getting this error?

**first original code** --->

```
 func loadFiles(resource: Resource) {
     //use the resource to get a resource-specfic token
     var er:ADAuthenticationError? = nil
     var authContext:ADAuthenticationContext = ADAuthenticationContext(authority: authority, error: &er)
     authContext.acquireTokenWithResource(resource.ServiceResourceId, clientId: clientID, redirectUri: redirectURI, completionBlock: {
 (result: ADAuthenticationResult!) in
```

**Then Xcode suggested this**---->

```
 var authContext:ADAuthenticationContext =
 ADAuthenticationContext(authority: authority as String, error: &er)
          authContext.acquireTokenWithResource(resource.ServiceResourceId,
 clientId: clientID as String, redirectUri: redirectURI,
 completionBlock: { (result: ADAuthenticationResult!) in
```

**when I try to compile it I get this error**-->

```
 cannot invoke 'acquireTokenWithResource' with an argument list of type
 '(NSString?, clientId: String, redirectUri: NSURL, completionBlock:
 (ADAuthenticationResult!) -> _)'

        authContext.acquireTokenWithResource(resource.ServiceResourceId,
 clientId: clientID as  String, redirectUri: redirectURI,
 completionBlock: { (result: ADAuthenticationResult!) in
```

Any help or idea will be very helpful
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

resource.ServiceResourceID is an NSString; Xcode is converting it to Swift types. This should work:

```
authContext.acquireTokenWithResource(resource.ServiceResourceId as! String,
 clientId: clientID as String, redirectUri: redirectURI,
 completionBlock: { (result: ADAuthenticationResult!) in
```